# Bind variables to async in expressjwt

Tags: node.js, async-await, express-jwt

I have a below scenario to pass a parameter from the calling function to the async function with the `expressJWT`.

```
module.exports = authorize;

function authorize(roles = ["test"]) {
    const secret = config.Secret;
    return expressJwt({ secret, isRevoked }).bind({ roles: roles});
}

async function isRevoked(req, payload, done, roles) {
console.log(roles) //undefined
}
```

Here, `authorize` function calling the async function `isRevoked` and there I want to pass the parameter `roles`.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to pass parameters to isRevoked? Can you elaborate on your question. It is a little unclear.

Comment: @skellertor, I have updated and you've already answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an intermediary anonymous function to grab the callback parameters req, payload, and done, then you can pass them with the roles array to the defined function. The roles array will be available to the _isRevoked function because of closures.

```
module.exports = authorize;

function authorize(roles = ["test"]) {
    const secret = config.Secret;
    return expressJwt({ secret, isRevoked: (req, payload, done) => _isRevoked(req, payload, done, roles)});
}

async function _isRevoked(req, payload, done, roles) {
    console.log(roles) // ["test"]
}
```